# linq can not find the value from database, although it exists in database

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I've noticed some irregularities while using linq in mvc3.

I have a database table with a "PIN" column. Column must have a 28 characters and completly random characters can be stored. Then I have a controller action:

```
    Function Unlock() As ActionResult
        Dim key As String = Request("token")
        If key IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim user As Users = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(Function(u) u.PIN = key)
            If user IsNot Nothing Then
                user.PIN = Nothing
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return View()
            End If
        End If
        Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", New With {.Area = ""})
    End Function
```

For example when PIN holds "Co/5c1mmil2e+clGK3c6JvdrGpQ=" key string reads that full string from querystring, but user reference always ends up nothing, even though that same value is stored in database.

On other hand when PIN holds "GbgI4QAaYWanaKWUm6j7Jg5IpA8=" everything works just fine. So I figured that maybe linq has problems with some characters like / or +, but how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try replacing single '=' with '=='

Comment: @bhuvin: This is VB.NET, there exists no ==

Comment: ohh @DanielHilgarth - sorry man ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
`u.PIN.Equals(key)`

Use intelliTrace while debuging it will help you a lot with linq.

Also FirtsOrDefault seams more reasonable for me in this case instead of SingleOrDefault

Comment: I havent noticed that Request("token") replaced + with empty space, so instead of direct insert of string into url bar it first needs to be url encoded. It was my mistake so it isn't up to linq. But I'll mark your answer for correct because it is more reasonable to use firstordefault